# hasRole check doesnt work with th:replace

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am having trouble getting a th:replace to work this is my thymeleaf:

```
<div th:replace="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE'')') ? 'fragments/first :: content(content=${content})' : 'fragments/second :: content(content=${content})'}"></div>
```

If I go to this page I get this error:

```
Error resolving template [${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE'')') ? 'fragments/upgradeblock], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "fragments/first" - line 36, col 34)
```

I think I have to change something in the Thymeleaf code but cant find out what.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the [correct syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#fragment-expressions) for this should look like:

```
<div th:replace="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE'')')} ? ~{fragments/first :: content(content=${content})} : ~{fragments/second :: content(content=${content})}"></div>
```

Even further, this [syntax](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451) worked for me as well:

```
<div th:replace="~{${'fragments/' + (#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE'')') ? 'first' : 'second')} :: content(content=${content})}"></div>
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split it like this:

```
<th:block th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE'')')}"> 
  <div th:replace="fragments/first :: content(content=${content})"></div>
</th:block>

<th:block th:unless="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE'')')}"> 
  <div th:replace="fragments/second :: content(content=${content})"></div>
</th:block>
```

Note that it can't be done by combining the `<th:block>` with the `<div>` due to [attribute precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence) of `th:replace` being higher.

Comment: `th:replace` has a higher [attribute precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence) than `th:if`/`th:unless` -- so you have to do something like this but the idea should work. `<th:block th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE'')')}"><div th:replace="fragments/first :: content(content=${content})"></div></th:block>`

Comment: Thanks for both your comments, only this is the thing I am trying to avoid. I now have 2 divs, one for !hasRole and one for hasRole.
My idea was if I can use a ternary operator I dont need both the divs.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @Metroids ! I updated my answer with your information.